# How to change key bindings for switching workspaces in gnome3?

Tags: shortcut-keys, keyboard, gnome, workspaces

I know that you can go into the System Settings->Keyboard->Shortcuts and change the bindings for switching between workspaces in the Navigation tab, but this isn't working for me. I can change many other things in Shortcuts, like the shortcut for opening terminal, but for some reason I cannot change the navigation bindings. Is there another way to change this or is there someway to get it to recognize my changes there?

And just so we are clear, I have tried changing it in the Navigation tab to <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>(LEFT/RIGHT/UP/DOWN)</kbd> and <kbd>F1/F2/F3/F4</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SUPER</kbd>+<kbd>(LEFT/RIGHT/UP/DOWN)</kbd>, but none of those work, it just doesn't respond to any of my changes and stays as <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>(LEFT/RIGHT/UP/DOWN)</kbd>....

Any help would be appreciated, I have been search for 2 days for this and everything says to change it in the System Settings->Keyboard->Shortcuts, but it doesn't work...

Comment: The issue persist on Linux Mint Cinnamon as well. [http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/71460/how-to-set-up-keyboard-shortuts-with-custom-modifiers-like-mod3-in-cinnamon]

Answer (score 22):

Finally I've found a solution.

It appears, that you need to manually edit settings with the `dconf-editor` (dconf-tools package).

To edit workspace keyboard binding one should use dconf-tool and edit settings under path `org -> gnome -> desktop -> wm -> keybindings`.

The syntax for keybindings is the same as in other Gnome editions and the same as displayed in "System Settings->Keyboard->Shortcuts".

Comment: Pretty useful when the Back and Forward Navigation shortcuts in Intellij didn't works, even after disabling the shortcut using the GUI tool.

Answer (score 3):

You can also set them in the console with

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-left "['<Control><Shift><Alt>Left']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-right "['<Control><Shift><Alt>Right']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-up "['<Control><Shift><Alt>Up']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings move-to-workspace-down "['<Control><Shift><Alt>Down']"
```

changing the given key combinations as you see fit.

<kbd>Left</kbd> and <kbd>Right</kbd> don't make much sense in vanilla Gnome 3, because the workspace layout is strictly vertical, but I use the [Workspace Grid extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/484/workspace-grid/), so that's why I listed them.