# How to disable the shortcut Ctrl-Alt-Arrow in GNOME 3.8

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, shortcut-keys, workspace-switcher

I mapped <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Up</kbd>/<kbd>Down</kbd> to open web-browser and email client but it didn't take effect. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Up</kbd>/<kbd>Down</kbd> still switch workspaces as the default setting of GNOME 3.8.

I have tried log-out/log-in. No good.

Comment: In Ubuntu 18.04 these shortcuts were shown as "Super+Down" and "Super+Up" but were actually Ctrl+Alt+Down and Up. In this case disabling these "Super" shortcuts was enough.

Comment: @AgustínLado In my Ubuntu 20.04 system, it's even more strange: the settings that I discovered there were: Super+PageUp/PageDown (to move between desktops in Navigation) -- note **Page**! -- but those were the bindings that prevented me from using Ctrl-Alt-Up/Down (not PageUp/PageDown) in Emacs. askubuntu.com/a/1367734/19753

Answer (score 120, accepted):

The new keybinding you define in 'Settings-->Keyboard-->Shortcuts-->Navigation' will get appended to the previous/default one.

It will become, for example.

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-down

['<Primary><Shift>Down', '<Control><Alt>Down']
```

I managed to remove the default keybinding using the following commands

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-down "['']"
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-up "['']"
```

This clears all defined shortcuts for those tasks. And then just use 'Settings-->Keyboard-->Shortcuts-->Navigation' to define the desired shortcuts.

Source : https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=982695

Comment: Didn't work for me on Ubuntu 12.04. I.e. used the above gsettings commands, restarted and still ctrl-alt-down/up will switch workspaces.

Comment: The window docking can be fixed via the CompizConfig Settings Manager. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/305092/ctrl-alt-arrow-key-doesnt-switch-workspaces

Comment: Worked on Ubuntu 15.04. :)

Comment: From all possible methods for removing gnome bindings, this is one is the most reliable one IMO. Worked for me on Fedora 23 - Gnome Shell 3.18... Thank you...

Comment: Worked on Ubuntu Gnome 15.10

Comment: Sometimes you may need to look it up using dconf as well: https://askubuntu.com/questions/171328/how-to-change-key-bindings-for-switching-workspaces-in-gnome3

Comment: This worked for me in Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: You can also set to '[]' instead of "['']"

Comment: I think instead of clearing the whole configuration it is better to keep the `'<Super>Page_Down/Up'`.  
`$ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-down "['<Super>Page_Down']"`  

`$ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-up "['<Super>Page_Up']"`

Comment: Worked for me on RedHat 8.2, gnome 3.32.2. I use Ctrl-Alt-Down in Pycharm.

Comment: worked for me on Ubuntu 20.04.4 with GNOME Shell 3.36.9

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works fine to me on Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS (Focal Fossa)

Comment: Works Ubuntu 20.04 thanks so much. Didn't know the same command could have 2 bindings, and the second binding wouldn't show on the UI. Also the bindings of switch-to-workspace-right and switch-to-workspace-left don't show on the settings UI either.

Comment: Worked on Ubuntu 22.04! The shortcuts settings said that Ctrl+Alt+Down conflicted with workspace down when I tried assigning the combination to another action, but workspace down did not even exist in the list of shortcuts!

Answer (score 8):

In Ubuntu 18.04
Settings->Devices->keyboard 
in navigation search for shortcuts: super+up and super+down and change it, save in button define.

Comment: Worked in 20.04. But why `super` is equivalent to `Alt + Ctrl` ?

Comment: @manikanta In my Ubuntu 20.04 system, it's even more strange: the settings that I discovered there were: Super+PageUp/PageDown (to move between desktops in Navigation) -- note **Page**, but those were the bindings that prevented me from using Ctrl-Alt-Up/Down (not PageUp/PageDown) in Emacs. https://askubuntu.com/a/1367734/19753

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me on Ubuntu 12.04

Go to "System Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Navigation".

Find the workspace switching shortcuts bound to CTRL-ALT-ARROW. For each one of them do this:

Click on shortcut (so it says "New Accelarator..." allowing you to change the shortcut). Now Press 'Backspace' to clear it. It now says 'Disabled' for that shortcut.

Comment: Do I need to restart for the changes to be applied?

Comment: It's been a long time ago I disabled this. I'm sorry I can't remember if worked 'instantly' or not.

Comment: Restart didn't do the trick. The settings are back to normal and changing them never had any effect.

Comment: The answer by @mac did the trick. The post also has a link to a site explaining the bug I experienced.

Comment: To me this is working in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. No restart needed. My hot key settings in Eclipse Mars conflicts with the system default ones.

Answer (score 2):

I know this thread is pretty old. 
For me (Xubuntu 16.04, Xfce4) it helped to use `xfce4-settings-editor` and then go to `xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts`. Then scroll down to `xfwm4` and "Reset" the bindings for the relevant shortcuts.

Answer (score 2):

(The question is more general than just about Ctrl-Alt-Up/Down. As for me personally, I had the problem that my Emacs didn't get Ctrl-Alt-Left/Right. So, I'd like to write an answer with the solution I have found for Ubuntu 20.04.)

Those pointing at the compiz settings were right (via `ccsm` available after `apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager compiz-gnome`, the latter one for `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/compizconfig/backends/libgsettings.so`, although I'm not sure that backend is actually used in my system):

- https://askubuntu.com/a/1194357/19753
- https://askubuntu.com/a/1123865/19753
- https://askubuntu.com/a/908997/19753 (specifically mentioning the Desktop Wall plugin and the Grid plugin)

I couldn't find the bindings for these keys via the normal Ubuntu settings menu.

What's new in my answer is that not only compiz's Grid plugin (under "Window Management") could have bound these keys (which you'd like to use in a different way), but also the Desktop Wall plugin (under "Desktop" in `ccsm`). Especially, the bindings with Left/Right could be found by me to be bound in the latter plugin.

For all 4 (left, right, up, down), you might want to look through the bindings of both these plugins in `ccsm` (and disable them). Or use the search tool in `ccsm` to search for "left", "right", etc. in all the values.

After I disabled these bindings in `ccsm`, Emacs immediately started getting these key combinations. (Finally! That has been so inconvenient for me for so long to have this problem in Emacs whenever I had to use an Ubuntu computer...)

To enable for me the use of Ctrl-Alt-Up/Down in Emacs, I had to look into the usual Ubuntu settings menu, as in https://askubuntu.com/a/1145043/19753 , however, I didn't see such bindings there in the Navigation section of key shortcuts. In despair, I tried disabling the following ones: Super-PageDown/PageUp (note **Page**!), and that helped.

Comment: OMG! `Super-PageDown/PageUp`. Thanks. You saved my life! :)))

Answer (score 1):

I tried @mac 's approach but I still could get rid of `Control+Alt+Up` keybinding. Reading Skype Book's comment [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=321094) pointed me in the right direction. What did the trick for me was to

1. install `dconf-tools`
2. run `dconf-editor`
3. Under `compiz->profiles->unity->plugins->grid`, removed `put-maximize key`

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu 22.04,

using Settings > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts > View and Customize Shortcuts > Custom Shortcuts > Add Shortcut,

create the shortcut you desire.

If your shortcut is bound to another action, it will prompt you that the previous shortcut will be replaced with yours. Confirm.

Then delete your newly created shortcut. You have successfully disabled the default shortcut. You can safely use it on any website.

Answer (score 0):

In Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye) GNOME Version 3.38.5 I had to remove the key bindings <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Page Up</kbd> and <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Page Down</kbd> from "*Move to workspace above*" and "*Move to workspace below*".

After:
[image: after]
*Settings -> Keyboard Shortcuts*

Before:
[image: before]