# Ctrl + Alt+ right/left is not consistent

Tags: unity, keyboard, shortcut-keys, workspace-switcher

The keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>right</kbd>/<kbd>left</kbd> does two different things:

1. If I have no windows selected, it changes workspace
2. If I select a window, it takes the window to the half right/ left of the screen.

I would like to have  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>right</kbd>/<kbd>left</kbd>, just switching workspaces, but I can't find a way. I have tried to edit the keyboards shortcuts menu, but it seems the only assigned action to that key combination is to switch workspaces:
[image: Screenshot of keyboard shortcuts]

I am using ubuntu 16.04

Comment: You will probably find the hotkey combination that makes a selected window tile in compizconfig-settings-manager. (Install that package to install the compiz configuration tool, where you can disable the key combination)

Comment: I installed compizconfig-settings-manager, but I can't find the key combination to disable it.

Comment: I also intalled gconf-editor, and still I don't seem to find how to change the window snaping behaviour. Thanks though.

Comment: I would have checked myself if I still were using Unity with compiz. I am pretty sure the option will be out there, but then, compizconfig-settings-manager is quite overwhelming, and you can quickly end up with a broken desktop. If that happens, you can reset compiz from the terminal with the command `dconf reset -f /org/compiz/`

Answer (score 2):

I found a way to fix the problem:

1. Install compizconfig-settings-manager

   ```
   sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
   ```
2. Run compizconfig-settings-manager. in the terminal type

   ```
   ccsm
   ```
3. Go to Window Management/Grid

[image]

4. Change the commands to Right Maximize, Left Maximize, Restore, and Maximize.

[image]

**It is worth noting that `ccsm` is an advanced tool. If you did something wrong and want to reset it, type:**

```
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
```